# The value of "multidimensional array pointer +1" doesn't match

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Here is the problem program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{   
    int apricot[2][3][5];
    int (*r)[5]=apricot[0];
    int *t=apricot[0][0];

    printf("%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n",r,r+1,t,t+1);
}
```

The output of it is:

```
# ./a.out 
0xbfa44000
0xbfa44014
0xbfa44000
0xbfa44004
```

I think t's dimension's value should be 5 because t is the last dimension,and the fact is matched(0xbfa44004-0xbfa44000+1=5)

But the r's dimension's value is **0xbfa44014-0xbfa44000+1=21,I think it should be 3*5=15**,because 3 and 5 are the last two dimensions,then why the difference is 21?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`r` is a pointer to an array of 5 ints.

Assuming 1 int is 4 bytes on your system (from `t` and `t+1`), then "stepping" that pointer by 1 (`r+1`) means an increase in 5*4 = 20 bytes. Which is what you get here.

Answer (score 1):

You get tricked by the C syntax. `r` is an *array pointer* to an array of int, `t` is a plain int pointer. When doing any kind of pointer arithmetic, you do it in the unit pointed at.

Thus `t+1` means the address of `t` + the size of one pointed-at object. Since t points at int and int is 4 bytes on your system, you get an address 4 bytes from `t`.

The same rule applies to `r`. It is a pointer to an array of 5 int. When you do pointer arithmetic on it by `r+1`, you get the size of the pointed-at object, which has size `5*sizeof(int)`, which happens to be 20 bytes on your computer. So therefore `r+1` gives you an address 20 bytes (==14 hex) from `r`.